# Laravel, Integrity constraint violation

Tags: laravel, sqlite, model, integrity

I pased two hours tryin fix this but no succes!

I'm trying to save a post, caption and it's image, and uder_id,

Here is the migrations file:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('user_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('caption');
        $table->string('image');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

```
public function store()
{
    $data= \request()->validate ([

        'caption'=>'required',
        'image'=>'',
    ]);

    auth()->user()->posts()->create($data);

    dd(\request()->all());
}
```

Here is the model

```
class posts extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = array(
        // Any columns you don't want to be mass-assignable.
        // Or just empty array if all is mass-assignable.
    );
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

Here is the View

```
<div class="form-group row">

    <label for="caption" class="col-md-4 col-form-label">post Caption</label>
    <input id="caption"
           type="text"
           class="form-control @error('caption') is-invalid @enderror"
           name="caption"
           value="{{ old('caption') }}"
           autocomplete="caption" autofocus>

    @error('caption')
        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
        </span>
    @enderror
    <div>
        <label for="image" class="col-md-4 col-form-label">post_image</label>
        <input type="file" , class="form-control-file" , id="image" ,name="image">

        <div class=" row pt-5">
            <button class="btn btn-primary "> Add new post</button>
        </div>

        @error('image')
            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
        @enderror
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is the error

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException
>   SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL constraint failed: posts.image (SQL: insert into "posts" ("caption", "user_id", "updated_at", "created_at") values (hh, 4, 2020-01-04 09:39:53, 2020-01-04 09:39:53))

hope we can fixt it!

Comment: `caption` and `image` are required in your migration file. Even though you only validate `caption` as required in your controller.

Comment: Does a `post` always require an image?

Comment: @PtrTon has point, read the error message - `19 NOT NULL constraint failed: posts.image (SQL:...`

it means there is no data for image field (posts.image) when doing insert  into posts. If you want data to be inserted to table with empty image or caption make them nullable or provide data. Though i cant see a use-case where that data should be nullable ...

Comment: Thanks for your answers, the reason why i only validate caption as required, is because when I tried to validate the image as required, even If I uploded an image, I got the message ' the image feild is required', means as you sais there is no image data even if I upload it! I'll try to find why is that!

Comment: I could not find why the data image is empty?

Comment: Please any help

Comment: Fixed, I had to add these two lines: value="{{ old('caption') }}"
                                autocomplete="image" autofocus>

Answer (score 0):

In your posts table migration, change

```
$table->string('image');
```

to

```
$table->string('image')->nullable();
```

Then in the store function do not make the image field required by taking off the image required validation like so ...

```
$data= \request()->validate ([

    'caption'=>'required'
]);
```